# Subtracting elements from sorted dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, subtraction, sorteddictionary

I have a sorted dictionary (here the bids of an order book) with the following form, where the items in the parentheses are {price: amount} and sorted.

```
bids = SortedDict({0.0005: 11.0, 0.006: 10.0, 0.01: 28.6, 0.0105: 21.8, 0.012: 25.1})
```

I also know my own quotes, which are:

```
own_bids = [{0.006: 10.0}, {0.012: 5.1}]
```

My goal is to exclude my own orders from the order book. The result should look like:

```
SortedDict({0.0005: 11.0, 0.01: 28.6, 0.0105: 21.8, 0.012: 20})
```

I have tried to delete them by looping through my own orders and deleting the elements if quantity is 0. But it increased the run time by 12x so I am wondering if there is no simple operation to do this. Is there a fast method to do this in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to substract `own_bids` from `bids` and filter the zero values out:

```py
bids = {0.0005: 11.0, 0.006: 10.0, 0.01: 28.6, 0.0105: 21.8, 0.012: 25.1}
own_bids = [{0.006: 10.0}, {0.012: 5.1}]

tmp = {k: v for d in own_bids for k, v in d.items()}

new_bids = {
    k: new_val for k, v in bids.items() if (new_val := v - tmp.get(k, 0)) != 0
}
print(new_bids)
```

Prints:

```py
{0.0005: 11.0, 0.01: 28.6, 0.0105: 21.8, 0.012: 20.0}
```

---

EDIT: Without the [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) (`:=`):

```py
bids = {0.0005: 11.0, 0.006: 10.0, 0.01: 28.6, 0.0105: 21.8, 0.012: 25.1}
own_bids = [{0.006: 10.0}, {0.012: 5.1}]

tmp = {k: v for d in own_bids for k, v in d.items()}

new_bids = {}
for k, v in bids.items():
    new_val = v - tmp.get(k, 0)
    if k != 0:
        new_bids[k] = new_val

print(new_bids)
```

Comment: Actually I noticed a small bug in the version without walrus operator. It has to be:
if new_val != 0:
        new_bids[k] = new_val

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is convert the *own_bids* into a *single dictionary* and use **Counter** from **Collections**.

```
    from collections import Counter

    bids = {0.0005: 11.0, 0.006: 10.0, 0.01: 28.6, 0.0105: 21.8, 0.012: 25.1}
    own_bids = {0.006: 10.0, 0.012: 5.1}
    sumWithZero = dict(Counter(bids) - Counter(own_bids))
    print(sumWithZero)
```

---

**Output**

```
    {0.0005: 11.0, 0.01: 28.6, 0.0105: 21.8, 0.012: 20.0}
```

Comment: But what will happen if user has `[{0.006: 10.0}, {0.012: 5.1}, {0.012: 1.2}]` ?

Comment: This solution works as well, but is slower compared to the one suggested by Andrej. 8.85 µs ± 397 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

Comment: You can use `{key_: value_ for x in own_bids for key_, value_ in x.items()}`
for converting your own_bids into dict regardless of its length. 
And then follow the same code.
The output then will be:
`{0.0005: 11.0, 0.01: 28.6, 0.0105: 21.8, 0.012: 23.900000000000002}`
@DeepakTripathi

Comment: No if you do this it will overwrite the same key with new value that way it will not work

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't realize that. Thanks for the response!
But I think the type of array you presented is not relevant to the question asked. And to take account of the type of array you presented, we can use `Itertools` and maybe take track of the `dict` with the same `key`.

Answer (score 0):

```
bids = {0.0005: 11.0, 0.006: 10.0, 0.01: 28.6, 0.0105: 21.8, 0.012: 25.1}
own_bids = [{0.006: 10.0}, {0.012: 5.1}]
my_dic = bids.copy()
for ele in own_bids:
    for k,v in bids.items():    
        if k in ele:
            my_dic.pop(k)
dict(sorted(my_dic.items()))
```

> output : {0.0005: 11.0, 0.01: 28.6, 0.0105: 21.8}

1. Copy bids list to make operations(pop)
2. Get the elements in own_bids list with using for loop
3. Get the bid items with using for loop
4. Check if "0.006" and "0.012" are in the list
5. If they are in, take them of my_dic
6. After loop, you can sort them and convert it again dictionary type

I hope, my solution is useful for you.